# fgets() not reading from a text file?

Tags: c, null, load, settings, gets

I have a function loadsets() (short for **load settings**) which is supposed to load settings from a text file named **Progsets.txt**. loadsets() returns 0 on success, and -1 when a fatal error is detected. However, the part of the code which *actually* reads from **Progsets.txt**, (the three **fgets()**), seem to all fail and return the null pointer, hence not loading anything at all but a bunch of nulls. Is there something wrong with my code? fp is a valid pointer when I ran the code, and I was able to open it for reading. So what's wrong?

**This code is for loading the default text color of my very basic text editor program using cmd.**

**headers:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 100

struct FINSETS
{
    char color[ARR_SIZE + 1];
    char title[ARR_SIZE + 1];
    char maxchars[ARR_SIZE + 1];
} SETTINGS;
```

**loadsets():**

```
int loadsets(int* pMAXCHARS) // load settings from a text file
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\Typify\\Settings (do not modify)\\Progsets.txt", "r");
    char *color = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*) * ARR_SIZE);
    char *title = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*) * ARR_SIZE);
    char *maxchars = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*) * ARR_SIZE);
    char com1[ARR_SIZE + 1] = "color ";
    char com2[ARR_SIZE + 1] = "title ";
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int found = 0;

    while (k < ARR_SIZE + 1) // fill strings with '\0'
    {
        color[k] = title[k] = maxchars[k] = '\0';
        SETTINGS.color[k] = SETTINGS.maxchars[k] = SETTINGS.title[k] = '\0';
        k++;
    }

    if (!fp) // check for reading errors
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unable to load settings. Make sure that Progsets.txt exists and has not been modified.\a\n\n");
        return -1; // fatal error
    }

    if (!size(fp)) // see if Progsets.txt is not a zero-byte file (it shouldn't be)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Progsets.txt has been modified. Please copy the contents of Defsets.txt to Progsets.txt to manually reset to default settings.\a\n\n");

        free(color);
        free(title);
        free(maxchars);

        return -1; // fatal error
    }

    // PROBLEMATIC CODE:

    fgets(color, ARR_SIZE, fp);      // RETURNS NULL (INSTEAD OF READING FROM THE FILE)
    fgets(title, ARR_SIZE, fp);      // RETURNS NULL (INSTEAD OF READING FROM THE FILE)
    fgets(maxchars, ARR_SIZE, fp);   // RETURNS NULL (INSTEAD OF READING FROM THE FILE)

    // END OF PROBLEMATIC CODE:

    system(strcat(com1, SETTINGS.color)); // set color of cmd
    system(strcat(com2, SETTINGS.title)); // set title of cmd
    *pMAXCHARS = atoi(SETTINGS.maxchars);

    // cleanup

    fclose(fp);
    free(color);
    free(title);
    free(maxchars);

    return 0; // success
}
```

**Progsets.txt:**

```
COLOR=$0a;
TITLE=$Typify!;
MAXCHARS=$10000;
```

**EDIT:** Here is the definition of the size() function. Since I'm just working with ASCII text files, I assume that every character is one byte and the file size in bytes can be worked out by counting the number of characters. Anything suspicious?

**size():**

```
int size(FILE* fp)
{
    int size = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}
```

Comment: I do not see any `fscanf` in your program.

Comment: Yeah. Typo on the title, sorry. It's supposed to be "fgets() not reading from a text file?"

Comment: your mallocing `char *` as `char **`, not checking returns for mallocs, and probably need to rewind the file after getting size

Comment: I think It suspect that the error caused the files have reached the end in `size(fp)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your use of the `size()` function. It repeatedly calls `fgetc()` on the file handle until it gets to the end of the file, incrementing a value to track the number of bytes in the file.

That's not a *bad* approach (though I'm sure there are better ones that don't involve inefficient character-based I/O) but it does have one *fatal* flaw that you seem to have overlooked.

After you've called it, you've read the file all the way to the end so that any further reads, such as:

```
fgets(color, ARR_SIZE, fp);
```

will simply fail since you're already at the end of the file. You may want to consider something like `rewind()` before returning from `size()` - that will put the file pointer back to the start of the file so that you can read it again.